# Damaged NTFS Partition by GParted

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, ext3

I've lost my 150 GB partition with family photos/videos and other valuable files.

I have an external 320 GB HDD, with (it was) partitions: [30 GB ext3 ubuntu bootable; 150 GB NTFS with family data (was 145 GB used, 5 GB free); 100 GB NTFS with data (worked); 20 GB unallocated space]

And I do this with GParted: (delete 30 GB ext3 partition, Apply, then Move 150 GB NTFS partition to left (to 0 cylinder?). And on this operation I have failed error.

Now my partitions looks like:

[150 GB ext3 with ubuntu files but without NTFS data; 100 GB NTFS worked; 20 GB unallocated ]

I've done testdisk runned, checkdisk runned but nothing helps.

chkdsk shows me my two NTFS partitions as 'Invalid', but can't fix it

What I can do?

Later I have worked external HDD with this partitions:

1. Linux 30 GB ext3 partition with Ubuntu (bootable, but I do not use it)
2. NTFS 150 GB with my videos, photos, and other costly stuff
3. NTFS 100 GB with my files (now it worked okay).
4. 20 GB of unallocated space (no partition)

in GParted I use 'Move/Resize' tool, and move second partition (150 GB) to left (change start cylinders or what, I don't know). On this operation i've got error. And now I have:

1. Linux 150 GB ext3 partition with Ubuntu (bootable, but I do not use it) (5 GB used / 145 GB free)
2. NTFS 100 GB with my files (now it worked okay).
3. 20 GB of unallocated space (no partition)

but chckdsk shows me my old two NTFS partitions 150 GB + 100 GB, and telling me that Damaged/Invalid.

How I can revert changes and restore my costly data on partition 150 GB
Which programm?

Comment: Yeah, you can't just go moving partitions around all willy-nilly. Things are bound to get corrupted. I can't even understand the question, though, so it's hard to help.

Comment: If it's important, create backups. Seriously. It's not *just* a plot by hard disk manufacturers to make more money. I hate to kick you when you're already down, but that really was an insane thing to do without backups. I hope you still get a useful answer though.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, you resized your 30 GB ext3 partition to a 150 GB one, nuking one of your NTFS partitions in the process. I hope I've misunderstood this. Because if I'm understanding this correctly there's absolutely nothing you can do to get those data back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys, I have use getDataBack programm. It return me 80% of my files. And R-Studio also help me return some files.

Comment: Do you maybe have a license for GDB? I need to use it once because I accidentally formatted my disk...

Answer (score 3):

If you've just damaged the partition table, all is not lost. The underlying data is likely still there!

As the original partition was NTFS, I'd recommend [findntfs](http://www.partitionsupport.com/utilities.htm). It's a command line utility that runs over the disk and generates a report of all files it finds.

It's a little tricky to get the syntax right, but easy to use once you've worked it out.

1. (Optional) Mount your damaged drive as read-only
2. Run findntfs from another drive that has enough space to recover your data
3. Generate a list of files and folders (**findntfs 2 0 1 1 files files.txt**), where numbers are CHS
4. In that list, find the folder with your photos, find its ID number (say 117)
5. Recover that folder! **findntfs 2 0 1 1 copy 117**

Answer (score 1):

Some years ago I suffered with the same problem. There is a program called [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). It works in a way to recognize your partitions... and I could recover "my precious" (my photos).

Comment: I use it ( but It cant do anything for me :( It tell me: two partitions: Linux150gb and NTFS100gb :( so.. sooo bad :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems the partition table got somewhat intertwined. It seems the partition table flag was not changed when you moved partitions around.

It is close to impossible to tell whether filesystem integrity is still OK. Now, that the partition tables got some damage.

I don't know any easy way of restoring the data off the top of my head. They only way would be looking for the FS boundaries and extract that into an image and then work on it with different kinds of software. However, that would be a forensic approach, and most data would stay damaged.

As a general rule, you should always do a backup of the most valuable date before working on partitions. An easy copy to a local hard drive or a USB stick would've done it well. As I understand it, you don't have such backups. In  this case you have to make either the forensic approach, or call it dead.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that a commercial data recover agency can fix this. It will cost you thousands of dollars (Euros).

DON'T USE THE DISK until you get it to the agency.